# Retrieving data from a different view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am not sure if using session or tempdata is useful for this problem or even if it is i have no clue on how to do this. (Still getting the hang of MVC with asp.net).

Basically in my first view which is called the payment view, i have many fields which users fill in to donate to a specific charity. Now in order for this to be added to the database and complete the donation, I will create a confirmation page which will transfer all the data and display a non-editable text format on the confirmation page, giving all the the information the user has given in the fields i created. On the confirmation page i would like to a have a button called "Edit" which will allow the user to go back to the payment page where the data they inserted is still stored but is able to be modified by just simply clicking to the input fields. I think using session or tempdata is best for this but i am quite confused as if i do use this, when the user clicks donate on the final confirmation page, will the restart the site? Such as clear all the saved data. This is what i want. I want a method that allows the user to edit the current data stored by clicking on "Edit" on a different view and able to modify it on the payment view.

**PAYMENT VIEW**

```
@model CharitySite.Models.Payment
....
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ....
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <h1>@ViewBag.Name</h1>
        <label> Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fullname" name="user_name" />
        <label> Amount:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ammount" name="user_ammount" />
        <label>Comment:</label>
        <input type="text" id="comment" name="user_comment" />
        <br /><br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    .... // more form controls
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" 
}


@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Payment Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Payments.ToList());
}

public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Payment payment = db.Payments.Find(id);
    if (payment == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(payment);
}

// GET: Payments/Create
public ActionResult Payment()
{
    var model = new Payment();
    model.ValidFrom = DateTime.Now;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Payment([Bind(Include = "ID,CardName,CardNumber,ValidFrom,Expires,CardSecurityCode,EmailAddress,Address,City,Country,PostCode")] Payment payment)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Payments.Add(payment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.Name = TempData["Name"];
        ViewBag.Amount = TempData["Amount"];
        ViewBag.Comment = TempData["Comment"];
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(payment);
}
```

Comment: Please do not just dump all your irrelevant code in a question. It not clear why you would need to redirect to a confirmation page, but if you do, then in the Payments() POST method you need to persist the data somewhere, preferably to a database, but it could be to Session. Then you need to redirect to a `Confirm()` method where you retrieve the data and display your confirmation page which would include you confirmation button (that posts to a `Confirm()` method and an 'Edit' link that redirects back to the `Create()` method.

Answer (score 0):

We won't be able to pinpoint your problem if you dump all of your code, so I'll mention some of the ways generally.

You can go about this in two ways:

1. You can put the data from the first page in the query string and do a redirect from the server. This works only if the data is manageable in size and not security sensitive.
2. If you have security sensitive information or just for better organization, you can have an extra model (table in the database) that represents an incompleted transaction.